# Minimum of cells in two matrices within a moving kernel

Tags: r, matrix, cells

I have two matrices `m1` and `m2`.

```
m1 <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
m2 <- matrix(16:1, ncol = 4)
# > m1
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13
# [2,]    2    6   10   14
# [3,]    3    7   11   15
# [4,]    4    8   12   16

# > m2
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   16   12    8    4
# [2,]   15   11    7    3
# [3,]   14   10    6    2
# [4,]   13    9    5    1
```

I want to find the minimum between the two matrices for each cell within a moving kernel of 3x3. The outer margines should be ignored, i.e. they can be filled with `NAs` and the `min` function should then have `na.rm = TRUE`. The result should look like this:

```
# > m3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    3    3
# [2,]    1    1    2    2
# [3,]    2    2    1    1
# [4,]    3    3    1    1
```

I have already tried a combination of `pmin{base}` and `runmin{caTools}` like this:

```
pmin(runmin(m1, 3, endrule = "keep"), 
     runmin(m2, 3, endrule = "keep"))
```

However, this did not work. Probably due to the fact that

> "If x is a matrix than each column will be processed separately."
>   (from `?runmin`)

Is there any package, that performs such operations, or is it possible to `apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base `R` approach:

```
m    = pmin(m1, m2)
grid = expand.grid(seq(nrow(m)), seq(ncol(m)))

x = apply(grid, 1, function(u) {
   min(m[max(1,u[1]-1):min(nrow(m), u[1]+1), max(1,u[2]-1):min(ncol(m), u[2]+1)])
})

dim(x) = dim(m)

#> x
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    3    3
#[2,]    1    1    2    2
#[3,]    2    2    1    1
#[4,]    3    3    1    1
```

Comment: This works fine for `m1` and `m2` being square matrices, but not with matrices with unequal `dim`s (try `m1 <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 4); m2 <- matrix(20:1, ncol = 4)`. Is it possible to adress this problem with your solution?